# How to guarantee Java instance control (without enum) in world of serialization?

Tags: java

In a world before Java 1.5 (so no `enum`) and with my object being serialized, how can I enforce proper instance control?  I'm talking about a class like this, where, as far as I can tell, I'm not sure that instance0 and instance1 will always be the only instances.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public final class Thing implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final Thing instance0 = new Thing();
    public static final Thing instance1 = new Thing();

    private Thing(){};
}
```

Comment: Get up to date. Even 1.5 is most of its way through its end of service life period.

Comment: Of course I'd love to - but it's not just up to me :(

Comment: jjujuma, I feel your pain. I deal with several clients that are scared of upgrading to the newest version of Java. So scared, in fact, some are still running 1.3! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really check out [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058). The chapter on Singleton addresses this somewhat, and there is a chapter on the Typesafe Enum pattern that was definitely an influence on the way `enum` was implemented.

The short answer is you have to implement `readResolve`.

Comment: Which is why I told jjujuma to go read the appropriate item from Effective Java.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then what you are looking for is to take Joshua Bloch' advice and implement the readResolve method to return one of your constant instances.

```
private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
  return PRIVATE_VALUES[ordinal];  // The list holding all the constant instances
}
```

Comment: ...which doesn't work securely, because the instance can be nabbed before readResolve.

Comment: Oh I see someone already mentioned Joshua's book. Highly recommended reading btw.

Comment: Tom, can you shed a bit more light as to why?