# Deserialize array that contains 2 objects with the same child using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My objective is to avoid the creation of the same object twice. I want to deserialize an array of two objects that contain the same child object, this is the JSON object that I want to deserialize

```
  [
     {
        @id: 98,
        relatedPackage: {@id:99, receivedOn:1374012807237, packingTypeFk:1,…}
     },
     {
        @id: 101,
        relatedPackage: {@id:99, receivedOn:1374012807237, packingTypeFk:1,…}
     }
  ]
```

and this is the POJO

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Package extends StampedModel {
...
}
```

In the last code you can see that I put the annotation  @JsonIdentityInfo to achieve my objective but it doesn't do the job. Always that I send this array to the server, it creates two diferent packages.

What am I doing Wrongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I need to send the first related package only one time, and the next times send only the ID number. ie.

```
[
   {
      @id: 98,
      relatedPackage: {@id:99, receivedOn:1374012807237, packingTypeFk:1,…}
   },
 {
      @id: 101,
      relatedPackage: 99
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the "identity" information does not enforce instance identity. It only ensures that two object conforming to that identity are regarded as equal.

You can implement [custom deserializers with Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers). Then you would also implement class [instance control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892304/how-to-guarantee-java-instance-control-without-enum-in-world-of-serialization) (either through an instance manager, or within the value classes themselves).
HTH